# Form in Material UI Dialog using React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get a form working inside of a Material UI Dialog component. If I wrap the Dialog in the form tags, they do not even show up in the resulting html (no idea why yet)...

```
<form onSubmit={someFunction}>
  <Dialog>
    ...
  </Dialog>
</form>
```

If I reverse it and put the form tags inside the Dialog, the form elements show up in the resulting html, but then the action button set to type="submit" will not fire the form's onSubmit.

```
<Dialog>
  <form onSubmit={someFunction}>
    ...
  </form>
</Dialog>
```

Has anyone had any success getting this combination to work? I know I can just call the function directly from the action button click, but I am also using Redux Form and have other non-dialog forms in the app, so I have it bound to the form element. So I really need to invoke the form submit from a Dialog somehow.

Answer (score 10):

Actually - I have/had the `onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.myFunction)}` to begin with and that was not the issue. The issue turned out to be how Material UI mounts the `Dialog` (which apparently is different than `react-toolbox`). They mount it on the body - I assume for easier positioning - so anything outside of the `Dialog` is ignored.

With the form inside the Dialog, the buttons are outside the form (which is again apparently different than `react-toolbox`). So to make it work, you have to use the HTML 5 'form' attribute as detailed [here](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/07/10/creating-a-jquery-ui-dialog-with-a-submit-button/) (along with a poly-fill for older browsers if needed). The form needs an `id` attribute and then the button outside it needs a form attribute with the value set to the id of the form. Then the form elements inside the dialog behave as expected. Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 6):

The material-ui Dialog component inherits from the material-ui Modal component, which means it accepts the prop "disablePortal" - which is false by default.

from the docs:
"Disable the portal behavior. The children stay within it's parent DOM hierarchy."
https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props

by default, the dialog is rendered as a child of your root html node, to have it render inside the <form> tag, you need to disable the portal behavior.

```html
<form onSubmit={someFunction}>
  <Dialog disablePortal>
    <DialogTitle>
      title!
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
      form fields go here
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <button type="submit">submit!</button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form onSubmit={someFunction}>
  <Dialog disablePortal>
    <DialogTitle>
      title!
    </DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
      form fields go here
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <button type="submit">submit!</button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Hey yeah I have this combo working... well I am using the Dialog component from react-toolbox which is very similar to Material-ui but they use Css-modules for styles instead of inline.

So the function you provide to the `onSubmit` attribute of the form element is going to be the `handleSubmit` function from redux-form. If you want to do anything such as dispatch actions and store the data then you will need to pass in an `onSubmit` function to the `handleSubmit` function. What happens is your `onSubmit` function is called with the values(object with properties of the values of your form) and the dispatch function from the redux store. You can see the [project](https://github.com/natac13/CareerSmartDemo/blob/master/app/components/ContactForm/ContactForm.js) I have which has the setup you are looking for.

Comment: The question is about material UI, and not about react-toolbox

Answer (score -3):

Instead of `onSubmit={someFunction}`, make it

```
 <Dialog>
  <form onSubmit={this.someFunction}>
    ...
  </form>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: The question is specifically for reverse scenario.