# form submission and material ui dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I have a material-ui form

```
 const actions = [
     <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Ok"
        type="submit"
        primary
        onTouchTap={this.handleTestSubmit}
      />,
    ];
 <form refs="testform" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.ActualSubmitMethod)}>
         <RaisedButton primary label="Submit" onTouchTap={this.handleOpen} type="button" />
                          <Dialog title="test"  
                             actions={actions} modal={false} open=
                             {this.state.open} onRequestClose={this.handleClose}>
                            Do you want confirm?>
                          </Dialog>
   </forms>
```

In this case I am either getting / xyz page not found error or nothing is being called.

For brevity actions handleOpen and handleClose are not added.

```
handleTestSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.refs.testform.submit();
  };
```

When I searched for examples, it showed the following ones

```
<dialog>
<form></form>
</dialog>
```

and certainly the above scenario doesnt serves my purpose

Comment: What do you meant by *When I searched for examples, it showed the following ones*? Please include as much as you can explain your problem with minimal amount.

Comment: I was referring to below URL  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263488/form-in-material-ui-dialog-using-react.  I also feel redux-form 'remote submit' is not a straightforward solution.